# How to unit test both cases of a void validate method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am writing a void validate method like this one:

```
void validate(SomeObject someObject) {
    if (check someObject with constraints) {
        throw new SomeException();
    }
}
```

To unit test this method, I would like to test both legal and illegal input:

- for illegal input, I used (expected = SomeException.class)
- I am wondering how we could test the case when someObject is legal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legal in this case means that the validation completes without exceptions. To test it you just need to call validate.

```
@Test
public void testLegal() throws SomeException {
     validator.validate(/* some legal object*/);
}
```

This test will fail only if an exception is thrown during validation.

Answer (score 2):

1st Test Case :

```
@Test
public void testOK() throws Exception {
    validate(someObject);
    // At Least 1 assertion
}
```

2nd Test Case :

```
@Test(expected=SomeException.class)
public void testException() throws Exception {
    try {
        validate(someObject);
    } catch(SomeException e) {
        // At Least 1 assertion
        throw e;
    }
}
```

In this 2nd test case, if the exception is not thrown, the test will fail because it expects SommeException.class.

At least 1 assertion is mandatory because you must verify that the exception that has been thrown is well the one you were expected.

Comment: `...the exception that has been thrown is well the one you were expected.` [expected](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html#expected()) already does that, doesn't it?

Comment: It only check the class, not the message. By example, if in your code have 2 paths that throw the same exception but with differents messages, you have to make 2 differents unit tests to assert the message, in order to be sure that the exception has been thrown where it should have been thrown.

Comment: Catching the exception, making some assertions then throwing the exception and at last making again another assertion (with `@Test(expected=..)` decreases definitively the readability of the test and that just with a tiny example. Why not simply writing  `fail(SomeException.class + " expected")` after the call to `validate()`  ? It would spare  `@Test(expected=..)`, the throw of the exception  and it eases the reading.

Comment: I don't think. For me writing `fail(...)` inside the `try` or writing `throw e` inside the catch is the same in term of readability. But the `@Test(expected=SomeException.class)` can show you fastly which tests are throwing exception and which tests are "normal" tests cases.

Comment: It is more verbose and it has more reading indirection. I don t see how it may be the same thing in term of readability. And in your case the expected exception in the annotation is less meaningful as we also see a catch of the exception in the test code. With more complex test , a fellow developer that doesn t code in this way may take time for being sure to understand the exception logic assertion.

Answer (score 0):

To test the case where `someObject` is legal, just call `validate` in a `try` block. If an exception is thrown, fail the test. If no exception is thrown, let the test end normally and pass, since that is the expected behavior.

Example would look something like:

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
    try {
        validate(new SomeObject());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail("expected no exception, but one was thrown.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example? Sorry I am new to JUnit.

Comment: @BoYuan Edited my answer with an example. Please remember to upvote and accept if this helped =]

Comment: Why would you use a `try` block? The test will already fail if an exception is thrown. No need to add a `try` block for no reason... it just makes the test harder to read. (4 of the 5 lines of your test body are pointless.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I just think it makes it more clear at first glance what exactly the test is testing for. I prefer readability to saving lines, but I wouldn't argue with you for doing it a different way if you included a comment / named the test in such a way that it was clear that the test was to see if an exception was thrown.